# Changing @Html.DisplayFor item after successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So the title pretty much says what I'm trying to do, I'm pretty sure I got the path right or at least I think so. But the value isn't updated until I reload the entire view

html:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AktivBalance)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BarBalance)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HasAllInclusive)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="changeaktbalance">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AktivBalance)
            </span>
            <br />
            <input style="width: 42%;" type="text" name="aktivAmount" class="viewedittext" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Indsæt" class="vieweditaddaktiv" data-childid="@item.ChildId" />
            <input type="button" value="Fratræk" class="vieweditsubaktiv" data-childid="@item.ChildId" />
            <br />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BarBalance)   
            <br />         
            <input style="width: 42%;" type="text" name="aktivAmount" class="viewedittext" />
             <br />
             <input type="button" value="Indsæt" class="vieweditaddbar" data-childid="@item.ChildId" />
             <input type="button" value="Fratræk" class="vieweditsubbar" data-childid="@item.ChildId" />            
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HasAllInclusive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Rediger", "Edit", new { id=item.ChildId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Detaljer", "Details", new { id=item.ChildId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Slet", "Delete", new { id=item.ChildId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

script:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // document ready
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(document.body).on("click", ".vieweditaddaktiv", function () {
            // test for at se om den får fat i de rigtige værdier, hvilket den gør.
            //alert("amount = " + $(this).parent().children(".viewedittext").val() + " id = " + $(this).data("childid") + ".");

            // værdierns sti bruges til at lave data variablen der skal videresendes. (ifølge vs bruger jeg nu de rette naming conventions i controlleren)
            var data = {
                Amount: $(this).parent().children(".viewedittext").val(),
                Id: $(this).data("childid")
            };

            // Jeg kan ikke sætte breakpoint og teste koden, der sker bare ingenting? Hvorfor virker intet herfra?
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Action("AddAktiv", "Default1")", // kalder på metoden der returnerer Json resultatet i controlleren.
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(returnedData) {
                    //alert(returnedData);
                    $(this).parent().children(".changeaktbalance").html(returnedData);

                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("An unexpected error has occured.");
                }
            });



        }); // End of vieweditaddaktiv.



    }); // End of document ready function.


</script>
```

I need only the particular displayfor in the parent dir of the button which fires off the script so I need to change the code in the ajax calls succes scenario but I'm not sure how?

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor is simply an HTML helper method that will get compiled into HTML.  By the time you are making AJAX calls, this has no relevance -- you'd need to manually modify the DOM.

Comment: post the action as well

Comment: Hm I think I understand what you mean, but I'm not quite sure how to change it? What actions are you referring to? If your worried about the controller method I have tested it several times and it works fine and always returns the correct data so it does indeed always enter the succes scenario of the script.

Comment: Is there a way I can just assign a class to my displayfor so I can find it and change it in the succes scenario of the ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside `jquery.ajax` success handler points to the ajax settings object of the current request. If you want to use it to refer to anything else - use the `context` option:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
    // rest of your code goes here
```

That way the selector you are using in the success handler should work